# AMP-friendly script for blogger ads

Tags: javascript, blogger

Assalamo alaicom,
I want to modify the following  script to become AMP-friendly so that I can use them in my blogger template .
What should I do do to make it AMP-friendly ?

```html
<div id='adsense-mohamed'><data:post.body/></div>
<div id='adsense-algandy'>
  Adsense CODe HERe
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function insertAfter(addition, target) {
    var parent = target.parentNode;
    if (parent.lastChild == target) {
      parent.appendChild(addition);
    } else {
      parent.insertBefore(addition, target.nextSibling);
    }
  }
  var adscont = document.getElementById( & quot; adsense - algandy & quot;);
  var target = document.getElementById( & quot; adsense - mohamed & quot;);
  var linebreak = target.getElementsByTagName( & quot; br & quot;);
  if (linebreak.length & gt; 0) {
    insertAfter(adscont, linebreak[1]);
  }
</script>
```

THE Second Script:

Comment: fixed indentation .. the second script is missing. And the question is incomplete. Please add the second script as mentioned in the question.

Comment: The second script is Similar , I mean if we solve this one, I won't need the second script